Which of the two solutions to find the circulation of a vector field around the boundary of the region is correct?
The Problem: Find the counter-clockwise circulation of a vector field $\vec{F} = (2x+7y)\vec{i} - (5y+3x)\vec{j}$ around and over the boundary of the region enclosed by curves $y=x$, $y=-x$, and $x=-2$ directly and by Green's theorem.

My friend and I both prepared the solutions to the problem, yet got completely different answers. I'm eager to sort out who did it wrong and why, which is the reason for me to publish this question.

Friend's Solution
We first construct the region bounded by three functions and mark the direction of the circulation by arrows.

For segment $CB$, we have line equation $y=x$, therefore $dy=dx$. We will integrate from $-2$ to $0$ by $x$-axis. Therefore:
$$
\int_{CB}\vec{F} d(CB) = \int_{-2}^0((2x+7x)dx-(5x+3x)dx) = \int_{-2}^0(2x+7x-5x-3x)dx=\int_{-2}^0xdx = \dfrac{x^2}{2}\Bigg|_{-2}^0 = -2
$$
For segment $BA$, we have line equation $y=-x$, therefore $dy=-dx$. We will integrate from $0$ to $-2$ by $x$-axis. Therefore:
$$
\int_{BA}\vec{F} d(BA) = \int_{0}^{-2}((2x-7x)dx+(-5x+3x)dx) = \int_{0}^{-2}(2x-7x-5x+3x)dx=\int_{0}^{-2}-7xdx = -\dfrac{7x^2}{2}\Bigg|_{0}^{-2} = -14
$$
For segment $AC$, we have line equation $x=-2$, therefore $dx=0$. We will integrate from $2$ to $-2$ by $y$-axis. Therefore:
$$
\int_{AC}\vec{F} d(AC) = \int_{2}^{-2}((-5y+3\cdot(-2))dy) = \int_{2}^{-2}(-5y+6)dy= \left(-\dfrac{5y^2}{2}+6y\right)\Bigg|_{2}^{-2} = -24
$$
The counter-clockwise circulation of a vector field $\vec{F}$ can be expressed as a contour integral $C = \oint_{ACBA}\vec{F}d(ACBA)$, which in turn is a sum of three line integrals: $\int_{CB}\vec{F}d(CB)+\int_{BA}\vec{F}d(BA)+\int_{AC}\vec{F}d(AC)$. Summing these up, we get $(-2)+(-14)+(-24) = -40$. Therefore, the answer is $-40$.
My Solution
We use the same drawing as for my friend's solution.
Let $C$ be the circulation in question. It can be found directly as a contour integral of the second kind:
$$
C = \oint_{ACBA}\vec{F}d(ACBA)
$$
By additivity, this integral can be represented as the sum of three line integrals $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$:
$$
C = C_1+C_2+C_3
$$
These three line integrals are the following ones:
$$
\begin{align*}
C_1 &= \int_{AC}\vec{F}d(AC) = \int_{AC}\left((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy\right) \\
C_2 &= \int_{CB}\vec{F}d(CB) = \int_{CB}\left((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy\right) \\
C_3 &= \int_{BA}\vec{F}d(BA) = \int_{BA}\left((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy\right) 
\end{align*}
$$
We compute them step by step.
We start from defining the coordinates of points $A$, $B$, and $C$.
Point $A$ is the point of intersection of lines $x=-2$ and $y=-x$. Therefore, $A_x = -2$ and $A_y = -(-2)=2$. We have obtained the coordinates of point $A\ \{-2;2\}$.
Point $B$ is the point of intersection of lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Therefore, since $x=-x$ if and only if $x=0$, we get $B_x = 0$ and $B_y = B_x = 0$. We have obtained the coordinates of point $B\ \{0;0\}$.
Point $C$ is the point of intersection of lines $y=x$ and $x=-2$. Therefore, $C_x=-2$ and $C_y=C_x=-2$. We have obtained the coordinates of point $C\ \{-2;-2\}$.
Now that we know coordinates of points $A$, $B$, and $C$, we can find the coordinates of direction vectors of line segments $AC$, $CB$, and $BA$. For that, we subtract the coordinates of the start point from the coordinates of the end point of each segment:
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{AC}_x &= С_x-A_x =  -2 - (-2) = -2+2 = 0, \\
\vec{AC}_y &= C_y-A_y = -2-2 = -4, \\
\vec{CB}_x &= B_x-C_x = 0 - (-2) = 0+2 = 2, \\
\vec{CB}_y &= B_y-C_y = 0 - (-2) = 0+2 = 2, \\
\vec{BA}_x &= A_x-B_x = -2 - 0 = -2, \\
\vec{BA}_y &= A_y-B_y = -2 - 0 = -2.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, we get the following coordinates of direction vectors: $\vec{AC}\ \{0;-4\}$, $\vec{CB}\ \{2;2\}$, $\vec{BA}\ \{-2;-2\}$.
From these coordinates, it is possible to construct parametric equations for lines $AC$, $CB$, and $BA$. We can take any of the two points of each line as a point this line passes through.
Parametric equations for line $AC$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = A_x + \vec{AC}_xt, \\ y = A_y + \vec{AC}_yt;
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x = -2 + 0t, \\ y = 2 + (-4)t;
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x = -2, \\ y = 2-4t.
\end{cases}
$$
Parametric equations for line $CB$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = C_x + \vec{CB}_xt, \\ y = C_y + \vec{CB}_yt;
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x = -2 + 2t, \\ y = -2 + 2t.
\end{cases}
$$
Parametric equations for line $BA$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = B_x + \vec{BA}_xt, \\ y = B_y + \vec{BA}_yt;
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x = 0 + (-2)t, \\ y = 0 + (-2)t;
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x = -2t, \\ y = -2t.
\end{cases}
$$
Now we will express differentials through parameter $t$ for each line.
For line $AC$:
$$
\begin{cases}
dx = d(-2), \\ dy = d(2-4t);
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
dx = 0, \\ dy = -2d(2t-1);
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
dx = 0, \\ dy = -4dt.
\end{cases}
$$
For line $CB$:
$$
\begin{cases}
dx = d(-2 + 2t), \\ dy = d(-2 + 2t);
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
dx = 2dt, \\ dy = 2dt.
\end{cases}
$$
For line $BA$:
$$
\begin{cases}
dx = d(-2t), \\ dy = d(-2t);
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
dx = -2dt, \\ dy = -2dt.
\end{cases}
$$
Now we find out values of $t$ on the endpoints of each segment. These will be our limits of integration. With that in mind, we can express $t$ from any of the two parametric equations of each line.
For line $AC$, we get:
$$
2-4t = y \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{y-2}{-4}
$$
For line $CB$, we get:
$$
-2+2t = y \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{y+2}{2}
$$
For line $BA$, we get:
$$
-2t = y \Leftrightarrow t = -\frac{y}{2}
$$
We find the lower integration bound for line $AC$ by point $A$, and the upper integration bound by point $C$:
$$
\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \frac{A_y-2}{-4} = \frac{2-2}{-4} = 0, \\
t_2 &= \frac{C_y-2}{-4} = \frac{-2-2}{-4} = \frac{-4}{-4} = 1.
\end{align*}
$$
We find the lower integration bound for line $CB$ by point $C$, and the upper integration bound by point $B$:
$$
\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \frac{C_y+2}{2} = \frac{-2+2}{2} = 0, \\
t_2 &= \frac{B_y+2}{2} = \frac{0+2}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.
\end{align*}
$$
We find the lower integration bound for line $BA$ by point $B$, and the upper integration bound by point $A$:
$$
\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \frac{B_y}{2} = \frac{0}{2} = 0, \\
t_2 &= \frac{A_y}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.
\end{align*}
$$
Now we prepare to calculate definite integrals.
We express $C_1$ through parameter $t$ with respect to line $AC$:
$$
\begin{align*}
(2x+7y)dx &= (2x+7y)\cdot 0 = 0, \\
(5y+3x)dy &= (5\cdot(2-4t) + 3\cdot(-2))\cdot(-4)dt = (4 - 20t)\cdot(-4)dt = (80t-16)dt.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, we can simplify the expression for integration:
$$
((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy) = 0 - (80t-16)dt = -(80t-16)dt = (-80t+16)dt
$$
We express $C_2$ through parameter $t$ with respect to line $CB$:
$$
\begin{align*}
(2x+7y)dx &= (2\cdot(-2+2t) + 7\cdot(-2+2t))\cdot 2dt = (18t-18)\cdot 2dt = (36t-36)dt, \\
(5y+3x)dy &= (5\cdot(-2+2t) + 3\cdot(-2+2t))\cdot 2dt = (16t-16)\cdot 2dt = (32t-32)dt.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, we can simplify the expression for integration:
$$
((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy) = ((36t-36)dt - (32t-32)dt) = ((36t-36) - (32t-32))dt = (4t-4)dt
$$
We express $C_3$ through parameter $t$ with respect to line $BA$:
$$
\begin{align*}
(2x+7y)dx &= (2\cdot(-2t)+7\cdot(-2t))\cdot (-2)dt = -18t \cdot(-2)dt = 36tdt, \\
(5y+3x)dy &= (5\cdot(-2t)+3\cdot(-2t))\cdot (-2)dt = -16t \cdot(-2)dt = 32tdt.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, we can simplify the expression for integration:
$$
((2x+7y)dx - (5y+3x)dy) = (36t-32t)dt = 4tdt
$$
Now we calculate definite integrals $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$:
$$
\begin{align*}
C_1 &= \int_{0}^1(-80t+16)dt = -24, \\
C_2 &= \int_{0}^1(4t-4)dt = -2, \\
C_3 &= \int_{0}^14tdt = 2.
\end{align*}
$$
Finally, we sum them all up to get the desired contour integral:
$$
C = C_1+C_2+C_3 = (-24)+(-2)+2 = -24.
$$

I've decided not to proceed to Green's Theorem based solution until I find out whoever of us is on the right track. Which one is correct? Or both are incorrect?

Your friend's solution is correct. Your method is correct, but you have an error early on that propagates throughout the calculation:
$$
\vec{BA}_y = A_y-B_y = \color{red}{-}2 - 0 = \color{red}{-}2
$$
should read
$$
\vec{BA}_y = A_y-B_y = \color{red}{+}2 - 0 = \color{red}{+}2\rlap{.}
$$
As a consequence, $\vec{BA} = (-2, \color{red}{+}2)$ so a nice parametric equation for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ is
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= -2t, \\ 
y &= \color{red}{+}2t,
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$
with differential
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
dx &= -2\,dt, \\ 
dy &= \color{red}{+}2\,dt.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Now, curve $C_3$ along $\vec{BA}$ is
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(2x+7y)\,dx &= (2\cdot(-2t) + 7\cdot(\color{red}{+}2t))\cdot (-2\,dt) 
= \color{red}{+10}t \cdot(-2)\,dt 
= \color{red}{-20}t\,dt, \\
(5y+3x)\,dy &= (5\cdot(\color{red}{+}2t) + 3\cdot(-2t))\cdot (\color{red}{+}2\,dt) 
= \color{red}{+4}t \cdot(\color{red}{+}2)\,dt 
= \color{red}{+8}t\,dt, 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
so its contribution to the line integral is
$$
(2x+7y)\,dx - (5y+3x)\,dy = (\color{red}{-20}t - \color{red}{8}t)\,dt = \color{red}{-28}t\,dt.
$$
Therefore,
$$
C_3 = \int_0^1(\color{red}{-28})t\,dt = \color{red}{-14}, 
$$
and the desired contour integral works out to
$$
C = C_1+C_2+C_3 = (-24) + (-2) + (\color{red}{-14}) 
= \boxed{\color{red}{-40}}, 
$$
which happily agrees with the calculation by your friend!
